# FileNotFoundException when file exists

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I am getting a FileNotFoundException. But the file exists.

Below is the code:

```
 try {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("conf/sampleprop.conf");
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         prop.load(fis);
         String file = prop.getProperty("FILE");
         System.out.println("File : " + file);



         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

and the output is:

```
File : "C:\Chithra\Contacts.txt"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Chithra\Contacts.txt" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at PropertiesTest.main(PropertiesTest.java:32)
```

But the file actually exits,
Can anyone help please

Comment: Is this running on Windows?

Comment: Yes in Windows using eclipse

Comment: give full code including the initialization of "file"

Comment: check the properity value loads the file name you are trying to read .

Comment: Yes... I am printing it... [in the first line of the output]

Comment: Why is your file name coming in double quotes?

Comment: remove the double quotes and store it as  FILE = C:\Chithra\Contacts.txt in properity file. Properity values should not used in double quotes

Comment: @Gk, does it matter? look [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: yes it will.[Refernce](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).see how to define the properity values

Comment: Yeah..It worked when i removed double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have the permission to read this file. See this post:

[Get FileNotFoundException when initialising FileInputStream with File object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999771/get-filenotfoundexception-when-initialising-fileinputstream-with-file-object)

Comment: But I ran using eclipse in Windows machine and I created the txt file

Comment: Try using canRead() and the isFile() method from the File class. See the first answer in the provided link.

Comment: Did you close your writer after writing the file ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the file name to be "C:/Chithra/Contacts.txt"

Do not use "\" in java, java reads file paths separated with "/"