# Files created but still throwing an exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to create and add files to that directory. And below is my code, I'm able to create and add files to them, but at the end it is throwing me an exception.
**My Code:**

**Unzip_Main.java**

```
import java.io.File;

public class UnZip_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String zipFilePath = "D:\\News\\Zip\\";
        String destDirectory = "D:\\News\\Zip\\Result\\";
        new File(destDirectory).mkdir();
        UnZip unzipper = new UnZip();
        File dir = new File(zipFilePath);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (null != files) {
            for (int fileIntList = 0; fileIntList < files.length; fileIntList++) {
                String ss = files[fileIntList].toString();
                if (null != ss && ss.length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("unzip path is ");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("dest directry is " + destDirectory);
                        unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath + ss.substring(ss.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, ss.length()),
                                destDirectory);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Unzip.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath, zipFilePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath, true));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
        File newName = new File(filePath);
        String str = zipFilePath.substring(zipFilePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, zipFilePath.lastIndexOf("."));
        File zipPath = new File(filePath);
        zipPath.mkdir();
        File oldName = new File(zipPath.getParent() + "\\" + str + ".xml");
        if (oldName.exists()) {
            oldName.delete();
        }
        System.out.println("new name is " + newName + "and old name is " + oldName);
        if (newName.renameTo(oldName)) {
            System.out.println("Renamed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Renamed");
        }

    }

}
```

**My output:**

```
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\If16c0c30613111e5850ddea403ecf0ba.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\If83120c05dd311e599a896be76e2f024.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\If8915610629d11e5b64da6abc0693b3d.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\If93445c0661f11e5839c9a236dd16599.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\If9bd10a061f411e5b445d6756f17230b.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\Ife581970612c11e5b64da6abc0693b3d.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\Ifed1c1f05f9a11e5bc448d3219668f6c.xml
Renamed
unzip path is 
dest directry is D:\News\Zip\Result\
new name is D:\News\Zip\Result\content.xmland old name is D:\News\Zip\Result\Iff5aa9905d4011e5bb1df062954439f5.xml
Renamed
```

**Exception at the end:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\News\Zip\Result (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at UnZip.unzip(UnZip.java:17)
    at UnZip_Main.main(UnZip_Main.java:19)
```

The files are created in correct folder, all of them are created, but still getting this exception, unable to know where I have gone wrong and how to fix it.

Another thing observed is if i change `String destDirectory = "D:\\News\\Zip\\Result\\";` to `String destDirectory = "D:\\News\\Zip\\";`, and if there is any folder inside `Zip` path, i'm getting the same above result with exception, else it is not throwing any exception.

Comment: what is the code in line 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a check for like this

if(files[fileIntList].isDirectory())
                    continue;

also you should change your file rename code it should be

**oldName.renameTo(newName)**

ideally you should remove new File(destDirectory).mkdir();

Comment: Can you explain why you should skip the first file?

Comment: because he is creating result folder in advance...ideally he should remove this line 
new File(destDirectory).mkdir();

Comment: Thanks @user3857593, this is awesome and what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the exception:

```
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
```

because you are giving it a directory ( **D:\News\Zip\Result** )

please make sure you are giving it a **file** path and not a directory path.

Try to put a breakpoint to check.

[Get FileNotFoundException when initialising FileInputStream with File object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999771/get-filenotfoundexception-when-initialising-fileinputstream-with-file-object)

Comment: Hi @jmcg, i was trying to push bulk files not a single file, so i gave directory path instead of a single file, can you please suggest how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a directory as a file.  Your `FileInputStream` is attempting to open `D:\\News\\Zip\\Result\\` which is a directory.

Comment: Hi Peter when i tried to print
`File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
  if (!destDir.exists()) {
   destDir.mkdir();
  }
  ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
  System.out.println("New paths si sa" + zipFilePath);
  ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();` the ouput i got is `New paths si saD:\News\Zip\Iff5aa9905d4011e5bb1df062954439f5.xml`, But this is file path instead of directory path. please correct me if i'm wrong